# Auto code grading system like codecademy's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, codemirror

I'm building a ruby on rails application with most of the views with react. I'm considering using CodeMirror as an editor for users to type in code. I want them to be able to submit the code, and the code will be run through some of my test cases and get results back, similar to how codecademy works.

What are some initial steps to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Keep It Simple. You want the grading? Do it first then. No react, no fancy editors, nothing. Just plain old rails. When you have it done, __then__ you add your bells and whistles.

Comment: The issue is that I already have everything set up with react. I'm trying to add this feature to an existing website.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Do it in a separate new application. Once you understand how it should be done, it'll be easy to add to that existing application of yours. Running and scoring user input is the hard part, not the fancy editors.

Comment: Alright thanks for the tip! I would appreciate any further hints as to how I can even begin implementing the grading on the new app ;)

Comment: The simplest thing is to `eval` user code with your test data input and compare the output with the correct one. Output matches? It's a PASS. Else it's a FAiL.

Comment: Didn't know about the `eval` function. I'll check it out. Thank you!

Comment: Once you have this working, now you worry about sandboxing user code so that it can't wipe your system or something (big problem, this one!)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the http://reactrb.org site.  There is live code editors on there.  Source code for the doc site is on github.

If the code examples are in either ruby or JS you can run the test scripts in the browser (for ruby you will use opal-rspec)  This makes sandboxing easy.

Sounds like a great project.  If you need additional questions or help stop in at https://gitter.im/zetachang/react.rb There are a couple of people there who can help you out with the details.